# What's the logic and wisdom behind punishing those who become nonMuslim?

Tags: fiqh, sharia, punishment, hudud

1. Why islamic sharia set such a harsh punishment for those who abandon religion islam? Isn't it against freedom of religion?
2. I read that Islamic state will compel and bound Muslims who inherit the religion islam. Otherwise warn him of punishment? If this is the case where is the freedom of choice if?
3. Islamic ullama say that this is ruling of Allah. If it is then why Allah is so much angry with who become kafir that he will not only him to live on this land but also punish him after he die. Isn't this against his mercy?
4. If a person was born Muslim but after he reached maturity chose to adopt other religion or none? What's wrong with this? Why shall islamic state kill?
5. Don't you think that freedom to choose religion and practice it, have different opinions respectfully without causing harms or posing threats or damaging the community is the right of everyone as long as he mind his own business? Why islam is so much concerned about them that he take away this right plus right of living? Why islam set unconditional punishment? Islam could have set restrictions or criteria?

Sorry for my bad english since I'm a minor and trying to learn islam.

Answer (score 0):

Asalamualaikum brother,
I will insha'Allah answer according to the numbers you provided.

But before that you have to know that
Allah has actually made it easier for the people, if someone has left Islam he is put in jail to rethink all this person has to do to escape is say I repented even if he is lying the people will let him go.

1.) When a parent finds out a child is messing around with something dangerous such as a knife they don't respond by giving the child sweets and praising him for having fun with knives instead they discipline the child so he doesn't return to doing the dangerous act again. What can be more dangerous than someone burning in hellfire forever ?? Therefore the warning/disciplinary action against those who do things which will lead them to such a dangerous fate is also severe and harsh In it serves as warning so people think very carefully about their future, this is because many people leave Islam based on a whim and ignorance.

Also this type of thing is not just within Islam but found within other religions only difference being they hide it from the common people and we don't.

As for your comment about freedom then this type of freedom also exists within western societies for example democracy, if people collectively choose a leader through a democratic system then you will find that once that leader is chosen he basically free to do what he wants, people choose a leader for example because he made a promise to make cost of living cheaper after he's elected he can go back on his word and not do what he promised and those who against him will be shutdown because naturally he's now elected and will not leave until next elections and those who riot are put in jail is this also freedom ?

People in western countries are forced into contracts such as insurance, passports agreeing to go to jail if breaking laws etc these are all none negotiable everyone has to agree you don't have the freedom to simply ignore the state and say I don't like this law therefore I will commit whatever I want you cannot send me to jail.

Truth is total freedom does not exist anywhere in the world.

2.) Muslims country rulers put people in jail or confine them until they repent to save them from making a mistake, i.e, some people do things out of emotion and anger or whim to give the person the chance to rethink the decision carefully about his choice for example some people out of anger of whom of suspicion divorce their wives even if they're innocent and later when the truth is revealed they regret it, similarly people who leave Islam are given the chance to rethink to save them from doing something dangerous which is to walk the path of the hellfire.

Furthermore, if he doesn't repent then he is given the prescribed punishment why ? Because they may pose a threat to peace and order within the Muslim community i.e, if he leaves people will found out, he on the other hand will actively attack the religion of Islam based on nothing but whims and ignorance, this will result in clashes and major outbursts in communities to save them that person is punished.

A form of this has existed and still does in some western countries through the death penality for betrayal of country, in American cival war a man was sentenced to death and hanged Infront of thousands of people who cheered on for his death because the man accidentally put the wrong flag up, these people have sentenced people to death for simply raising the wrong flag !! And they ask why do we punish those who pose a risk to the communities peace ??
If you look at the logic behind why countries kill betrayers of country you see it's because those people poses a threat to law and order based on whims and lies. To protect the community such things are carried out.

3.) As explained before the logical reasoning behind the punishment is for the protection of the community against someone who will spread hatred and lies which fuel tensions between the people leading to mass killings. You can see examples of this with your own eyes, If you look at all the people who left Islam online they all try to gain fame by mocking and ridiculing Muslims and that's because they have the platform and place to openly spread hate speech in an Islamic state this would be worse because the majority would be Muslim and spreading hate against Muslims in a muslim country will lead to nothing be mass killings. Examples of this have been seen in India.

The mercy of Allah SWT is for greater than his wrath, Allah promised to give you whatever you wish whatever you desire and all he asked from you is to worship him. So is it so wrong that we get punished for denying a creator who will give us anything we can imagine in exchange for simply believing him or are we the tyrants who have no right to exist yet still Allah SWT out of his mercy created us so that he can reward us yet despite that we go against him every day. In exchange for everything he wants 1 thing.

4.) I believe I answered this above aswell.

5.) This is true there have been times where people during early muslims rules time who left Islam were not killed and later on during muslim rules such as ottomans, simply put the ruling has to be looked at carefully from what the scholars say about each individual person we do cannot go around killing whoever we think left Islam, this can only happen in an Islamic state through a legal system, there is a chance the person maybe forgiven but idk the full legal ruling.

Comment: To quote "But before that, you have to know that Allah has actually made it easier for the people, if someone has left Islam he is put in jail to rethink all this person has to do to escape is say I repented even if he is lying the people will let him go.", doesn't that make the person who just lies for escape from the prison a false Muslim? Why would Islam want that?

Answer (score -2):

The punishment for apostasy is death in the light of hadith, and scholarly consensus. This is because islam is a partial religion of sword which imposes its will upon you. If you don't believe me read the fatawas of extremist salafi sites.